How to identify if a transparent material is made of glass or plastic from an image alone?
Without using any spectroscopy instruments, how to identify if a transparent material is made of glass or plastic (taking the below image as example)?

Background: I've noticed that the optical properties of transparent acrylic and glass are very similar. Can I use some simple clues to determine which material an optical (transparent) component is made of?

The bending allows you to find the index of refraction. Then you can compare with known indices of refraction and that would be a first guess.

@naturallyInconsistent Thanks for your comment! I tried this approach, but after searching online, I found that both glasses and plastics come in a wide variety of types, and their refractive indices can be very close to each other.

Hmm, ok, but why is it that you need to distinguish materials with this little information? Why not just test the piece or something?

As said above - do you only have the image ? Or can you physically test the piece itself e.g. find its density or hardness ?

@naturallyInconsistent I noticed an interesting optical phenomenon from an online image. Being able to determine whether the material is plastic or glass would help me analyze this optical phenomenon.

@gandalf61 No, I have no any other information. I know this question might be a bit demanding, but I've tried my best to think about it on my own, and I haven't been able to succeed. Ultimately, I had to resort to seeking help from this site.

If you are only given an image taken by someone else, you have a tough luck. There is hardly any way to tell organic from inorganic glass just from the shape of the beam alone. On the other hand, plastic (acrylic) tends to be mechanically much softer than glass, and therefore quickly gets scratched, as opposed to glass, which is pretty hard. In your image, the presence of visible  scratches suggests that it is likely plastic (glass can be scratched, but the scratches typically look more rugged and chipped ("fresh") on glass).
If, on the other hand, you are allowed to have a look yourself, my best advice is to fetch a pair of cheap polarizers (e.g. a pair of good sunglasses) and look at the block in question placed between two crossed polarizers. Typical plastic is optically birefringent (often non-uniformly, due remnant stress), while glass is not. So if it is glass, you will still see nothing through your pair of polarizers, whereas if it plastic, you will see quite a lightshow. Since there is no wavlength specificity here, this method is not spectroscopic.
